# Determine if Textboxes Contain Values MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have a WPF page which consists of multiple text boxes and a search button. When one presses the search button the program needs to enumerate all the controls to determine if at least one of the textboxes is filled. If all are empty error then an error will be shown. The mvvm-light pattern is being used.

How does one enumerate all the textboxes under MVVM

Answer (score 3):

There's an easy way that you can achieve your goal.

You can create a `ViewModel` and create properties in this ViewModel, so you can bind these properties to your TextBox on XAML, doing so your properties on ViewModel will maintain the value of the textbox's, here's an example.

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

"Mode=TwoWay" means whenever the bind property change, the textBox will be updated automatically.

**XAML Code behaind.**

```
public MainWindow(){
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
```

You need set the DataContext in order to be able to bind the properties.

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel{
    private string _name;
    public string Name{
        get{
            return _name;
        }

        set{
            _name = value;
        }
    }

    private int _age;
    public int Age{
        get{
            return _age;
        }

        set{
            _age = value;
        }
    }
}
```

That is it, everytime when you need to check if your TextBoxes are empty, you can do so checking if your properties on View Model are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this logic to enumerate the controls and inform the user of its status.

1. Bind each of the controls on the view to individual properties on the View Model.
2. Create a method on the ViewModel, maybe called `AreAllBlank` (?) to enumerate each of the properties checking whether they are blank or not. If they are all blank, return `true`, otherwise return `false`.
3. On the view, for the button press's code behind operation, call the method created in step 2. If the result shows that they controls do not have data call `MessageBox.Show()` with an appropriate message.

Comment: Thanks for the information, here i have a doubt, how efficiently we can verify all the text boxes are empty instead of checking string.IsNullorEmpty() to each and every text box control